# polymorphic class for thumbs_up voting gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rubygems, vote-up-buttons

I want to make a generic voting controller for lots of different controllers.

I'm using the Thumbs_up gem which was formerly the vote_fu gem.

https://github.com/kitop/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voter.rb

My form looks like so which is a partial with the object @voteable:

```
<strong class="result">Votes: <%= voteable.votes_for - voteable.votes_against %></strong>

<%= form_tag user_votes_path(current_user) do |f| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :up %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :down %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :voteable, @voteable %>
    <%= submit_tag :vote %>
<% end %>
```

However when I try passing the voteable object into the controller directly it doesn't work.

> undefined method `base_class' for
>   String:Class

My question is then how to polymorphically look up the same object... ie pass the voteable_type and _id instead of the object itself... Unless there is some other easier way?

Controller looks like this

```
  def create
    #@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.vote(params[:voteable], :direction => params[:thumb_direction], :exclusive => true)
  end

#routes

  resources :users do
    resources :votes
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did something like this

```
  def create
    voteable_class = params[:voteable_type].constantize
    voteable_id = (params[:voteable_type].downcase + "_id").to_sym
    voteable_instance = voteable_class.find(params[voteable_id])
    current_user.vote(voteable_instance, :direction => params[:thumb_direction], :exclusive => true)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

And changed my routes for the nested voting resource on each model I wanted to use it.

## erb

```
<%= form_tag [voteable, Vote.new] do |f| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :up %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :down %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :voteable_type, voteable.class %>
    <%= submit_tag :vote %>
<% end %>
```